# How do I add legends when there are two y variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

This is the code I used:

```r
ggplot(Delays2006, aes(Month)) + geom_point(aes(y = delay), color = "blue", size = 2) 
+ geom_point(aes(y=delay2)) + scale_x_discrete(limits=(month.name))
+ labs(x= "Months", y = "Delays in minutes") + ggtitle(" Flight Data 2006")
```

This is the output:

[image]

May I ask how do I add legends to delay and delay2 in this graph. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. do `geom_point(aes(y = delay, color = "delay")) + geom_point(aes(y=delay2, color = "delay2"))`. Colors and labels could then be set via `scale_color_manual`.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hp, color = "hp")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = cyl, color = "cyl")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(hp = "blue", cyl = "green"), labels = c(hp = "Horse Power", cyl = "Cylinders"))
```

[image]